# Amazon S3 Requests Usage seems high

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been using the AmazonS3 service to store some files.

I have uploaded 4 videos and they are public. I'm using a third party video player for those videos (JW Player). As a new user on the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), my free PUT, POST and LIST requests are almost used up from 2000 allowed requests, and for four videos that seems ridiculous.

Am I missing something or shouldn't one upload be one PUT request, I don't understand how I've hit that limit already.

Answer (score 3):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for Amazon S3 includes:

- 5GB of standard storage (normally $0.023 per GB)
- 20,000 GET requests (normally $0.0004 per 1,000 requests)
- 2,000 PUT requests (normally $0.005 per 1,000 requests)

In total, **it is worth up to 13.3 cents every month!**

So, don't be too worried about your current level of usage, but do keep an eye on charges so you don't get too many surprises. You can always [Create a Billing Alarm to Monitor Your Estimated AWS Charges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html).

The AWS Free Tier is provided to explore AWS services. It is not intended for production usage.

Comment: Yes I started to notice the cost after some use and I wasn’t to worry about it. I’m guessing there’s more to it behind the scenes that I don’t understand with the put and post or get but the times it happens don’t bother no more. Thanks for the answer and for the prices.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very hard to find out the reason for this without debugging a bit. So I would suggest you try the following debugging :

1. See if you have cloudtrail enabled. If yes, then you can track the API calls to S3 to see if anything is wrong there.
2. If you have cloudtrail enabled then it itself put data into the S3 bucket that might also take up some of the requests.
3. See if you have logging enabled at the bucket level, that might give you more insight on what all requests are reaching your bucket.
4. Your vides are public and that is the biggest concern here as you don't know who all can access it.

Setup cloudwatch alarms to avoid any surprises and try to look at logs to find out the issue.

Comment: Yes i searched cloudtrail and there are Events called "PutBucketPublicAccessBlock" so when i hit upload of a video, does it use one request or several?

Comment: You might want to read below documentation to understand this clearly : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-management-and-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html